# Getting arrows of same length

Tags: tikz-arrows

```
$$\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\node (A) at (1,0) {$0$};
\node (B) at (2,0) {$H^1(G/H,M^H)$};
\node (C) at (3,0) {$H^1(G,M)$};
\node (D) at (4,0) {$H^1(H,M)$};
\node (E) at (5,0) {$0$};
\path[->,font=\scriptsize,>=angle 90]
(A) edge node[above]{} (B)
(B) edge node[above]{$\phi$} (C)
(C) edge node[above]{$\psi$} (D)
(D) edge node[above]{} (E);
\end{tikzpicture}$$
```

How may I change the length of the arrows such that they all have the same length? I want to try and standardise the lengths of my arrows for the whole document if that is possible.

Also, I realised that if I used a smaller scale, i.e. scale=2, then because of the size of the terms `$H^1(G/H,M^H)$, $H^1(G,M)$` and `$H^1(H,M)$`, they end up overlapping.

Comment: Please don't use `$$`, use `\[` and `\]` instead. A MWE would also help

Comment: May I just ask what the difference is?

Comment: @HaikalYeo see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: @cgnieder: you were faster than me :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length of the arrows is determined by the distance between the terms.

You can use a single row matrix to position the terms with the same sep between them.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix(m)[
      matrix of math nodes,
      column sep=1cm% sep between columns
    ]{
    0 & H^1(G/H,M^H) & H^1(G,M) & H^1(H,M) & 0 \\};
% arrows:
  \foreach[count=\i,evaluate={\j=int(\i+1)}]\text in {{},$\phi$,$\psi$,{}}
    \path[-angle 90,font=\scriptsize](m-1-\i)edge node[above]{\text}(m-1-\j);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can use the `graphs` library (needs pgf/TikZ version 3.0):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,graphs,quotes}
\tikzset{
  graphs/mathgraph/.style={
    math nodes,
    /tikz/>=angle 90,
    grow right sep=1cm,% sep between nodes
    edge={font=\scriptsize},
    fresh nodes
  }
}

\begin{document}
\[\tikz\graph[mathgraph]{0 -> "H^1(G/H,M^H)" ->["$\phi$"] "H^1(G,M)"->["$\psi$"]"H^1(H,M)" -> 0};\]

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

While for an exact sequence arrow with the same length may be preferable, this won't do for commutative diagrams. However, long arrows don't improve the appearance, in my opinion.

You can do it without TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\lto}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{document}
This has long arrows
\[
0 \lto H^1(G/H,M^H) \lto H^1(G,M) \lto H^1(H,M) \lto 0
\]
and this has short ones, which I prefer,
\[
0 \to H^1(G/H,M^H) \to H^1(G,M) \to H^1(H,M) \to 0
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]